# Emacs bookmark-jump: how to jump to bmark and only one of the split-windows changes contents?

Tags: emacs, bookmarks, emacs23

I start with a file visible in one window; then i do a split-window, therefore now both windows show the same contents (at same buffer point).

Now I want to jump to a different location in the file via a bookmark in only 1 of the 2 windows, but when i execute the bookmark-jump, both windows end up at the bookmark's point.

Leave the other window's point alone!

How can i configure this?

Thanks

(running on linux, GNU Emacs 23.2.1; xemacs does not behave this way)

---

post-note:

What I'd like to do is to have the same file shown on both windows, and while one window (w1) shows a section of the file, in the other window (w2) I jump around to different sections, using the various bookmarks, while w1's position does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering own question (after a couple of years):

started using emacs 24 (24.3.1), which "fixed" this unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a direct answer, but in general, I find that all kinds of things get inconvenient when displaying the same buffer in multiple windows. I recommend using [**indirect buffers**](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indirect-Buffers.html#Indirect-Buffers). Run `M-x clone-indirect-buffer` to create another buffer, or `C-x 4 c` (`clone-indirect-buffer-other-window`) to also show the new buffer in another window. An indirect buffer has the same contents as the original, and saving saves to the same files, but the buffers have

- independent points, marks, markers;
- independent modes (and more generally independent local variables);
- independent views (narrowing, hidden text, faces, …).

Comment: thanks for the answer and (for me) a new feature; but it won't work for me for 2 reasons; I use bmarks extensively (set/jmp) and... 1) when i create an indirect/clone buffer it doesn't seem to allow me to create a bookmark ("buffer not visiting a buffer"), and more important 2) when i refer to a bmark within the cloned buffer, it jumps to the bmark, but also switches the window back to the original buffer.

Comment: @jd: Oh, sorry, I hadn't realized that, but it makes sense. Markers and registers are associated with buffers, but bookmarks are associated with files, so they don't work in indirect buffers (which aren't visiting a file). I wonder if it's possible to make bookmarks work sensibly in indirect buffers, that sound useful…

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but provides an alternative solution to your problem. I use [bm.el](http://www.nongnu.org/bm/) for visible bookmarks. If the same file is visible in two windows then jumping around using visible bookmarks only modifies the point in the current buffer.

I've configured the package with the following:

```
(require 'bm)
(setq bm-highlight-style 'bm-highlight-only-fringe)

(global-set-key (kbd "<C-f2>") 'bm-toggle)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f2>") 'bm-next)
(global-set-key (kbd "<S-f2>") 'bm-previous)
```

Comment: thanks; installed it and tried it, but as you mentioned it's an alternative, with added functionality but not needed in my case. still hoping that there is a simpler solution.

Comment: @jd I don't ever use bookmarks, but this sure is an annoying feature. Try splitting the buffer in to three windows and running `bookmark-jump`, the point is only changed in two of them!

Answer (score 1):

If you use clone-indirect-buffer-other-window with bookmark+ and autonamed bookmarks (C-x p RET / C-x p n / C-x p p), it will work how you want.  Without the clone, bookmark+ seems to have the same problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function(I swear, copied from the internet) to do the splitting. using this I think you can get what you but order of doing is reverse.

1) open another file using bookmark.
2) split the window.

```
;;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; When splitting window, show (other-buffer) in the new window
;;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
(defun split-window-func-with-other-buffer (split-function)
  "dont just dumb split window, change buffer as well"
  (lexical-let ((s-f split-function))
    (lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (funcall s-f)
      (set-window-buffer (next-window) (other-buffer)))))

(global-set-key "\C-x2"
        (split-window-func-with-other-buffer 'split-window-vertically))
(global-set-key "\C-x3"
        (split-window-func-with-other-buffer 'split-window-horizontally))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that won't work.  I added a note to my original question explaining some more what I want to achieve.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try [***Bookmark+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus).  It does *not* change the window point in other windows as you describe.